# How to set cursor visible android in EditText but not set the textbox editable?

Tags: android

I know how to set the cursor visible in an EditText. But I dont want the EditText in itself to be clickable and editable without using the buttons in my application.

Consider an scientific calculator where you have the blinking cursor, but I dont want the user to be able to click on the textbox. How can I accomplish this?

in my my main file I did set:

```
   inputText.setCursorVisible(true);
```

where inputText is of class EditText.

```
   <EditText  
    android:id="@+id/textIn"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:editable="false" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="100dp" 
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:background="@drawable/inputview1"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_marginLeft = "5sp"
    android:layout_marginRight = "5sp"/>
```

Comment: set editable false for that edit-text in xml file.

Comment: Works better but the cursor is not blinking now. And also I can still move around the cursor myself by clicking on the text in the box.

Comment: set cursor visible true.(Post your xml code)

Comment: Yes I aldready did that, still does not work.

Comment: what do you actually want.. to disable input that means while clicking the edittext you dont want any keyboard?

Comment: Actually I want to have a blinking cursor inside a TextView. I.e. I want to see the blinkingcursor but I only want to be able to modify the text contents using myTextView.setText("Hello!") for example. And in that case I want the cursor to blink at the end of the text.

Comment: if you add property in your XML file android:cursorVisible="true" for your text view, After adding this in textview property, it will say cursorVisible should not be used with textView. i think you got your ans why its not working. I am not sure, but you can try to with EditText.